# how to use Fetch GET command with params in react js

Tags: ajax, reactjs, fetch

i want to use this ajax command in fetch command in react js

```
  var data = {
                resource_id: '5f5afc43-639a-4216-8286-d146a8e048fe', // the resource id
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

how can i use that command in Fetch command?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), this example use [JSON placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
  headers: { ContentType: "application/json" },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(console.log);
```

for your code it might be something like this but, unfortunatly the API you are requesting requires access token, so its not tested:

```js
var data = {
  resource_id: '5f5afc43-639a-4216-8286-d146a8e048fe', // the resource id
};
fetch("https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search", {
  headers: { ContentType: "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(data);
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search', {
headers: {'ContentType': 'application/json'},
body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => response.json()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Comment: is your environment the browser or nodejs?

Comment: my environment is browser

Comment: you might have an old browser that does not support fetch?
try using:
https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: While this code might solve the OP's question, it is better to add context, or an explanation to help future visitors understand this solution to prevent similar issues in their own code, and help users focus on what is important or unique about this code.

Answer (score 0):

i succeeded, i just put the ajax command in the react project and it's worked